# Redirecting from an October / Laravel installation

Tags: wordpress, laravel, .htaccess, octobercms

I have a web site built with October (built on Laravel) and the .htaccess file is pointing all request into the index.php page as expected. I want a separate directory off the www root folder to point to a blog into which I will install a WordPress instance. so the folder structure will look like this:

```
www/
  .htaccess
  artisan
  index.php
  /blog <-- i want to install the WP blog here
  /bootstrap
  /config
  /modules
  /storage
  /themes
  /vendor
```

I have tried Redirect but I'm not great on .htaccess and don't want to risk downtime with the site by getting it wrong

There are a bunch of RewriteCond statements which use ! to block certain folders and then the standard RewriteRule's to filter requests to index.php

I'd like to have something which would check for /blog in the incoming request and bypass the index.php, sending the request to /blog where my WP installation resides.

Here is .htaccess currently (default for October CMS)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    ##
    ## You may need to uncomment the following line for some hosting environments,
    ## if you have installed to a subdirectory, enter the name here also.
    ##
    # RewriteBase /

    ##
    ## Uncomment following lines to force HTTPS.
    ##
    # RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    # RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

    ##
    ## Black listed folders
    ##
    RewriteRule ^bootstrap/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^config/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^vendor/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/cms/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/logs/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/framework/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/temp/protected/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/app/uploads/protected/.* index.php [L,NC]

    ##
    ## White listed folders
    ##
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/.well-known/*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/uploads/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/media/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/temp/public/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/themes/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/plugins/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/modules/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
    RewriteRule !^index.php index.php [L,NC]

    ##
    ## Block all PHP files, except index
    ##
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
    RewriteRule !^index.php index.php [L,NC]

    ##
    ## Standard routes
    ##
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

thanks, Wittner

Comment: Do you want the same domain name for the two websites ? It's not ideal for the use of cookies and session variables

Comment: hmmm, hadn't thought of that... In the final analysis I might use blog.thedomain.com but this is really in the interim but thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you could post the problem area of your `.htaccess` file. Regardless, try adding this `RewriteCond` above where the `RewriteRule` is redirecting to `index.php`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog(.*)$
```

Comment: Thanks Gary. I don't have a problem area as such as the .htaccess works fine out of the box. I just wanted a new rule which would deal separately with /blog. I'm gonna try your solution now...

Comment: Nah! Still getting a 404. I'll add the entire contents of the .htaccess to the original post so you can see the current state of play.

Comment: Got it working using this:

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/blog/"

    RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to make an alias ?

In your octoberCMS apache conf (located in the apache conf.d directory) you can add this line :

```
Alias /blog /path/to/www/blog
```

Comment: no joy :( 404 I'm going to simplify my .htaccess if I can and see if I can stop October grabbing the url before it redirects. That's the default .htaccess file there and it looks a bit 'overcrowded' to me. Maybe a simpler one would work better...